# Media Querie en etiqueta link en html no funciona modo landscape

Tags: html, mediaqueries

Hola segun la documentación esta es la forma correcta de insertar el media querie, para decirle al navegador que el valor minimo para que se aplique es de 960 o en orientacion landscape, pero no funciona.

```
<link
    rel="stylesheet"
    href="/components/mediaqueries/desktop.css"
    media="only screen and (min-width: 960px), orientation: landscape"/>
```

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.